# Is there any way to get the result with conditions without where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to query and apply conditions whitout "where" clause? I have to to use a sql query which uses the  company table:

[image]

and location table:

[image]

and out put the result which is :

[image]

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: It's possible, but what's the condition  (why only these results) ?

Comment: just getting company ID 3,4,5 or Company Name E,D,C

Comment: Why do you want to do this without using where? Just curious...

Comment: Why is the `Location` needed at all? You seem to have only columns from the `Company` table in the result.

Comment: I tried to give a simple example; it is not needed here but in my real query it is needed! Thanks :)

Comment: `Obscure Requirement + No Practical Purpose == Homework Problem.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct CompanyyID, CompanyName 
from company c join location l on c.CompanyID = l.CompanyID and c.CompanyID >= 3
```

Comment: That's a bit of a cheat isn't it?  Nice use of the magic number, there.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit unclear what are the conditionals you need to use to write the query, my guess is "get all the companies in Toronto with more than 20 employees"?

Anyway, you have a way of writing such a query using the join conditionals

```
select C.companyID, C.companyName 
from company C join location L on 
(C.companyID = L.companyID and L.city = 'Toronto' and L.numberOfEmployees > 20)
```

As you can see you can include all the conditionals you need without using a where clause.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a table that identifies only the Company ID's of the records you want in the output, and INNER JOIN that table to the Company table in your query.